# C# WPF Slider AutoToolTipPlacement styling

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, tooltip

Right now I am stuck on how to style a tooltip which is in AutoToolTipPlacement of a Slider. Is there any method to do it? I need to be able to change the structure and the text of the tooltip.

During my research I have found this https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/09/14/modifying-the-auto-tooltip-of-a-slider/ , but can't figure out how to style.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, when the AutoToolTipPlacement is enabled, it shows the tooltip, which I have to style. The answer that I found very prosaic - just use a style on a C# demand. So, we have the simple addition to the code from https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/09/14/modifying-the-auto-tooltip-of-a-slider/

```
private ToolTip AutoToolTip
{
    get
    {
        if (_autoToolTip == null)
        {
            FieldInfo field = typeof(Slider).GetField(
                "_autoToolTip",
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

            _autoToolTip = field.GetValue(this) as ToolTip;

            _autoToolTip.Style = this.FindResource("SomeCoolStyle") as Style;
        }

        return _autoToolTip;
    }
}
```